# How to properly import .node addon into the type-script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following piece of code from my app.ts. Improc is a node addon that allows me to do some c++ image processing magic :

```
const improc = require("../build/Release/improc.node");
improc.brightness(
          uploadDir + fileName,
          parseInt(req.body.value),
          fileName
        );
```

Require is not part of ts. How can I change this statement to ts import?

Comment: `import` isn't a TS thing, it's a JS thing. If you want type information, you will need to provide a declaration describing the addon in the same manner as you would for any module.